# Unable to see store icon in outlook on POP/IMAP server

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am working on outlook addin. But to add addin to outlook I need to see store icon. See image 1.

[image: This image does not show store icon.]

but when I switch to exchange mail server inbox i start seeing store icon. See image 2. 
[image]

I am using outlook for mac 16.16.4. please let me know if this is mandatory requirement or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store functionality is only available for Exchange accounts, just the way Outlook works. Keep in mind that installed web addins are account based, so for multiple Exchange accounts you will have different addins, and for non-Exchange account you will have none.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it. I thought the same. i could not find any well documented proof from Addin documentation. I don't understand why someone downvotes my  question.